# JSONP parseerrror

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I'm making crossdomain call with code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: data.Url,
    mimeType: "application/javascript",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: false,
    cache: true,
    jsonpCallback: "getData",
    success: function(data){
        callback(data.html); 
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert('Error during downloading ebook component:'+ componentId + ' thrownError:' + thrownError);
    }  
});
```

Server response with:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: YIPtShlPtOmDcIvn3ldRVkONQJTDxFba7OFWnL44A5HVZFXL0+9gGTnO/uZ5muFi
x-amz-request-id: AF6CF3B66F843250
Date: Mon, 08 Aug 2011 11:32:52 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 08 Aug 2011 11:24:51 GMT
ETag: "ee72cfb6fea66192a34b4fa72796b260"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 30
Server: AmazonS3

getData({{"html":"example"}})
```

And as you may guess, error handler is executed with thrownError: 'getData was not called' and xhr.statusText: 'parseerror'.

Any Ideas? I'm pretty sure that I run this code sucessfully at friday(I've compared code with repository, but no diffrence), so I'm guessing it is something with server response.

Comment: SO is awesome, 2 minutes after I posted this question I found the answear.

Obviously JSON object was not correct, there should be one pair of parenthesis, and semicolon:

    getData({"html":"example"});

Comment: @Eric jsonp: false because I don't want jquery add ?callback=... to url, cause this file is stored on amazon S3 and then url must not be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{{"html":"example"}}` is not a valid JSON syntax that's why you are getting parse error.

Try this instead `{html:"example"}`